# как распараллелить работу с массивом данных

Tags: python

есть цикл for, который пробегается по огромному массиву. время работы не радует, но имею идею, как упростить это всё. как можно реализовать чтобы параллельно выполнялся цикл for до середины массива, а вместе с ним, цикл с середины и до конца, чтобы сократить время

Comment: ну идея у вас есть - реализуйте. в чем, собственно проблема ? тем более что в интернете достаточно примеров как многопроцессовой обработки, так и многопоточной.

Comment: не знаю как реализовать данный вопрос. думал глянуть в сторону threading или asyncio, но результатов на практике не дало

Comment: ваша функция обрабатывает массив или отдельный элемент ?

Comment: у меня есть на входе список с множеством строк, который мы уже непосредственно и обрабатываем

Answer (score 1):

Есть два общих случая (для примера взял функцию возведения числа в квадрат):

1. Ваша функция обрабатывает массив.

```
from threading import Thread

long_array = list(range(10**3))

def calculate_array(array): # ваша функция для обработки массива
    for element in array:
        print(f'{element}**2={element**2}')

threads = [
    Thread(target=calculate_array, args=(long_array[:len(long_array)//2], )),
    Thread(target=calculate_array, args=(long_array[len(long_array)//2:], ))
]

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

2. Ваша функция обрабатывает отдельный элемент.

```
from threading import Thread

long_array = list(range(10**3))

def calculate_element(element): # ваша функция обработки элемента
    print(f'{element}**2={element**2}')

def calculate_array(array): # пишем обертку для возможности разделения на потоки
    for element in array:
        calculate_element(element)

threads = [
    Thread(target=calculate_array, args=(long_array[:len(long_array)//2], )),
    Thread(target=calculate_array, args=(long_array[len(long_array)//2:], ))
]

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: спасибо вам огромное за решение проблемы, обнял!

Comment: Если в обработке массива в основом вычисления (а не ввод-вывод), то использование потоков не даст прироста из-за GIL, а даже замедлит все. Может помочь использование процессов, но это тоже далеко не факт, что поможет. Все сильно зависит от того, что именно делает обработка.